# Upload GeoJSON to GeoServer using CURL

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geonode, curl

I tried to upload a zipped shapefile to GeoServer using CURL.

```
curl -v -u username:password -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @D:\curl\bin\roads.zip https://DOMAIN/geoserver/rest/workspaces/geonode/datastores/my_geonode_data/file.shp
```

This above command works fine.

But I can't seem to upload a GeoJSON file to GeoServer.

```
 curl -v -u username:password -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/json" --data-binary @D:\curl\bin\countries.geojson https://DOMAIN/geoserver/rest/workspaces/geonode/datastores/my_geonode_data/featuretypes
```

I am attaching the error in geoserver.log. But the GeoJSON is not uploaded. I can't see it in the uploaded layers. Am I correct in the CURL command? Is the endpoint (URL address) okay?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default GeoServer doesn't support GeoJSON as a storage format because it is a text format with no indexing.

It would be possible for an expert to add the GeoTools `gt-geojsondatastore` module to GeoServer to add this support but it would be very unwise for a production service as that jar is currently unsupported and it would be very slow.

You should convert your data to a better format such as a PostGIS data base or GeoPackage and upload that instead.