# Upload shapefile to GeoServer using JavaScript REST API

Tags: shapefile, javascript, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to programmatically upload a map into GeoServer as a layer.
The user requirements as such that this data has to be uploaded from memory directly into GeoServer, using JavaScript.
I looked up the REST API documentation and tried many things.
I have posted the following posts one after another trying many approaches

Can anyone guide me in any approach in which I can upload to GeoServer using JavaScript REST API?

I am willing to use any data format, as long as it can be done through JavaScript REST API, but not Nodejs.

- [Upload shapefile to GeoServer using JavaScript REST API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422714/upload-shapefile-to-geoserver-using-javascript-rest-api)   (Previous error)
- [Using Javascript to upload GeoJSON to Geoserver as a layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422161/using-javascript-to-upload-geojson-to-geoserver-as-a-layer) - posted posted after (and based on) this post
- [Uploading GeoJSON as shapefile to GeoServer using REST API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422302/uploading-geojson-as-shapefile-to-geoserver-using-rest-api) -  posted posted after (and based on) this post
- [Upload GeoJSON to GeoServer using CURL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422278/upload-geojson-to-geoserver-using-curl) - posted posted after (and based on) this post
- [Using Javascript to upload GeoJSON to Geoserver as a layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422161/using-javascript-to-upload-geojson-to-geoserver-as-a-layer)

Here is the latest code and error from GeoServer logs.

```
 function UploadMap()
 {   
    var shapeFile;  //store the shapefile from url    
    console.log("Retrieving Shapefile to Load");
    var httpRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest(); // asynchronous request
    httpRequest2.open("GET", "https://docs.mapbox.com/help/data/stations.zip", true);
    httpRequest2.send();
    httpRequest2.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {     
            shapeFile = this.response;
            console.log("shapeFile2 " + shapeFile2);
        }
    });      
 
    console.log('Loading Shapefile: ');  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("XHR.Open");
    xhr.open('PUT', 'https://DOMAIN/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws/datastores/my_geonode_data/file.shp', true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');  //;type=geojson   
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("USERNAME:PASSWORD"));
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log('responseText: ' + this.responseText);
    };

    console.log("Sending file for upload, XHR.Send ");         
    xhr.send(shapeFile);    
    var responseObject = xhr.responseText;
    console.log('responseObject' + responseObject); // ------- Test status of upload
}
```

Error returned in console
[image: Error returned in console]

Error within Geoserver.log file

```
    2022-02-03 02:03:55,568 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - Error occured unzipping file
    org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Error occured unzipping file
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.AbstractStoreUploadController.handleFileUpload(AbstractStoreUploadController.java:132)    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.DataStoreFileController.doFileUpload(DataStoreFileController.java:577)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.DataStoreFileController.dataStorePut(DataStoreFileController.java:263)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor511.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMeth 
    odAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
at org.geoserver.rest.util.RESTUtils.unzipFile(RESTUtils.java:271)
at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.AbstractStoreUploadController.handleFileUpload(AbstractStoreUploadController.java:117)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the zip file is valid and contains all the files needed? What does the GeoServer log file say

Comment: I have just added another similar post in which I try to upload a shapefile from an online shapefile link. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422765/tried-many-ways-to-load-map-onto-geoserver-using-javascript-rest-api

Comment: you need to break this down in to simpler steps - 1. can you upload that zipped shpaefile to geoserver using curl (or other command line tool)? if you can't then the issue is with the file if you can then the problem is with your javascript.

Comment: Yes, I can upload the zipped shapefile using CURL, as follows
curl -v -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @D:\curl\bin\roads.zip https://DOMAIN/geoserver/rest/workspaces/geonode/datastores/my_geonode_data/file.shp

Comment: then this is a javascript issue - more of the geoserver log file might help, you are looking for the section starting `caused by`

Comment: added caused by lines within error in post

Comment: there is no data in the zipfile that GeoServer has received

Comment: Should I use formdata?
     var formData = new FormData();    
     formData.append('file', shpFile , 'zipfile.zip');